# use loops inside echo statement

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, echo

I want to use for loop inside echo statement and I have used following code but its getting error can anyone please help me?

```
$a = "<select class='formfield_select'   name='return_pickuptime_hh' id='rhh' disabled='disabled'>
                      <option value='' selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>Hour</option>
                      ".for($i=$data['timeh'];$i <= 24;$i++) {."
                      <option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>
                      ". } ."
                    </select>";
```

This code is in ajax part so i need this whole html as one variable so that i can replace this part
The error is like this
syntax error, unexpected T_FOR in CI/application/controllers/lha.php on line 748

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_FOR in CI/application/controllers/lha.php on line 748

Comment: that error is because a for loop is not meant to be appended to an string

Comment: see the below answer its work

Comment: for loop in echo its not possible...you have to change it

Comment: Any good reason to use for loop in a echo ? [PHP : how to use foreach loop inside an echo statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197581/php-how-to-use-foreach-loop-inside-an-echo-statement)

Comment: its not possible to use select statement with one statement for echo

Comment: This is not python my friend, where you can say something like "\n".join(["<div>"+html+"</div>" for html in contents]) which resolves to a single, concatenate-able string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

id recommend either building your options first then appending them to your echo string like so:

```
$optionString = '';
for ( $i = $data['timeh']; $i <=24; $i++ ){
 $optionString .= "<option ...>".$i."</option>";
}
```

or making 2 echos to open and close the select and a loop with the option echo in the middle eg

```
echo "<select ...>";

for ( $i = $data['timeh']; $i <=24; $i++ ){
 echo "<option ...>".$i."</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
```

Comment: sorry but i need this html part in one variable

Comment: then i would set a variable like `$htmlString`... set it to your opening select string. use the above for loop to append the options. after the loop append the closing select tag - and echo it all out at once

Comment: @chirag Then replace the first `echo` with `$string=`, and the remaining ones with `$string.=`. Then `$string` will contain everything in one variable, which can be `echo`'d.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
echo "<select class='formfield_select'   name='return_pickuptime_hh' id='rhh' >
                  <option value='' selected='selected' >Hour</option>
                  ";


                  for($i=0;$i<=24;$i++) 
                  {

                  echo "<option value=$i>$i</option>";

                   } 

                echo "</select>";
```